# Looking for a word from the The Lord of the Rings world that represents money/wealth

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

The company where I work we name internal software after characters/things from The Lord of the Rings universe. I will be creating a new project for the marketing department and I'm scratching my head thinking of a character/object/city that represents wealth/success.

As I was asking this question, Smaug came to mind because of his hoard of gold, but Smaug has a negative connotation to it (i.e. greed vs. success).

Is there an affluent city or person that you can think of that would be a good name for our new marketing software?

**EDIT:**

Everyone really likes your ideas guys but since we use **Frodo** as a main app, the marketing guy though that **Bilbo** might be a good choice. In case you're wondering we have **Palantir** that runs on a giant wide screen for viewing order statuses and we're thinking about using **Sauron** for another "all-seeing eye type dashboard".

Also, a couple ideas the company had were: **Mordor**, **Wormtoungue**, and **Gimli**. I guess marketing wasn't opposed to having their application named after an evil character.

Thank you everyone for your contributions!

Comment: [Erebor](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Lonely_Mountain). Also, can I just say--your job sounds amazing.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville yeah there are lot of gamers/nerdy/sci-fi folks in every department. Its great! If you post this as an answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: You might double-check with legal to make sure [The Tolkien Estate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolkien_Estate) won't hunt you down.

Comment: @BESW its ok, this is internal software that is only used by employees of our company. But you're point has been taken.

Comment: I know this is late, but what did you go with? Is it still working?

Answer (score 16):

I suggest **Arkenstone**.

It represented the wealth of the Kings under the Mountain, and was much sought after by the greedy.

It also rhymes with "Marketing", for bonus points.

Comment: For certain definitions of "rhyme"...

Comment: While we went with something else, this was a company favorite.

Answer (score 8):

[Gondolin](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Gondolin). The Hidden City of the Noldor. Good name for a marketing project as it was Hidden, everyone was looking for it, and it was very very rich.

Alternatively you could use Gimli -

> "I say to you, Gimli son of Glóin, that your hands shall flow with
>   gold, and yet over you gold shall have no dominion. "

Comment: Awesome, love it!

Answer (score 5):

I'd go with Moria or Mithril.

**Moria** - in the first age/second age it represented the dwarven height of wealth. It wasn't until they went too deep did things go wrong.

**Mithril** - not gold or silver or precious gems did the dwarves lust after more than this stuff. Lightweight but very strong, mithril was worth ten time that of gold and did not tarnish.

Comment: Great idea. I thought about Moria after posting this also. Now that I think about it, any Dwarven city might be good because of the idea that we will be "data mining" for information we can use to make money.

Comment: Just don't wake the Balrog.

Answer (score 4):

**Dáin** might be good. As Glóin tells Frodo at the banquet before the Council of Elrond:

> ... Dáin was still King under the Mountain, and was now old (having passed his two hundred and fiftieth year), venerable, and fabulously rich.

Answer (score 2):

Baggins.
He wasn't short of a bob or two.